C-code in Golang. Gortsplib client-play-format-h264
I'm trying to launch gortsp example: https://github.com/bluenviron/gortsplib/blob/main/examples/client-play-format-h264. But I have a problem with h264_decoder.go: "exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in %PATH%":

I installed TDM-GCC (https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/) which contains C-compiler.
If I try to launch some simple C-code in go it works.

Follow the Error, you need to Install pkg-config when already installed, add path to env

Where I can get libraries libavcodec, libavutil, libswscale ?

Just Google ffmpeg Windows build (dynamic linker)
